# How to prevent auto increment on exception?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

There is an entity Score where
record_id is autoincremented

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "record_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getRecordId() {
    return recordId;
}
```

but there can be errors on some operations

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Score record = new Score();
try {
    session.save(record);
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) { ...
```

the problem is that on errors record_id counter internaly increments
and on next successful save operation there is a gap beetwen lines in database, for example, where 69 and 71 are writes on success operations but on 70ts there was an error.

```
69   1    6    2016-12-03
71   2    6    2016-12-03
```

Is there a way how to prevent that increment on errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to avoid this, but you shouldn't care either.

The increment on the sequence is a one-way operation. This is done for performance. Incrementing a sequence must be an atomic operation, because multiple processes may need to insert rows concurrently, which requires interleaving ids.

Gaps in ids are expected in situations where inserts explode or someone manually does some operation that chews up some ids, or lots of reasons. You can't absolutely prevent it.

Importantly, your application shouldn't care about gaps. An auto incrementing key is a surrogate key whose value should not be relied upon to be anything in particular. If your system needs continuous ids, that's a design smell.

Answer (score 0):

The **innodb_autoinc_lock_mode** handles this. In one mode there is a lock to prevent a second auto_increment see:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/auto_increment-handling-in-xtradbinnodb/

Comment: This is not working. Still have the auto increment issue on exception

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be addressed if you use SEQUENCE Generation for ID instead of IDENTITY.

Sequences increments only when the record is created in the table.